# Problem with Updater & Software centre : Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Reading package list fails when I apt- update

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-center, update-manager, elementary

I recently was runnning the *auto updater* and I got the red circle with a white line within saying:

```
A problem occurred when checking for updates
```

After reading a few of the forums here, I tried to delete the file manually but *software centre* would not open as well. Or rather close after a few seconds that it was opened without showing any information.

Going by similar problems I tried to sudo purge Updater/Chrome etc. and also tried :

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* -rf
```

How ever when I run the command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it says `reading lists` and then stops at 89% (o/p  below)

```
Get:135 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/restricted Translation-en [460 B]                                                                       
Get:136 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed/universe Translation-en [5,876 B]                                                                       
Fetched 21.4 MB in 31s (668 kB/s)                                                                                                                             
s@sEOS:~$ sts... 89%
```

I have the same problem with `apt dist-upgrade`

That is it seems to stop at 89% with sts. What is sts, why could it be stopping there? FYI any of the changes that I want to make don't seem to be taking place so the `sudo apt-get update` is not working.

I am not too sure what is wrong and how do I correct it.

Comment: With regards to "sts" do you use something called spring tool suite ? Every time I look for "sts" in relation to Ubuntu or debian or linux I always find this https://spring.io/

Comment: No I do not use the spring tool suite , (or atleast I have not added it myself) . So unless it was pre installed or got added on in one of the updates, it is probably unlikely that this refer to it. Please note that when i do sudo apt-get update/upgrade, this reads as " reading package lists ...xx%"  . The xx going up from 0 until it hits 89% where I am left with the message shown.

Comment: Can you try just disabling those two repos listed, open software and updates app from dash  and choose "other software" tab, untick those two repos, apply, then try the update again, should be fine they are only "proposed" ones

Comment: Thanks Mark, the problem is dont have a dash. I tried installing it but that would require everything using the software store or sudo apt installing it both of which are not working. Is there another way to do the changes suggested by you?

Comment: Ok I figured out what the sts was : its just the last 3 letters of : " Reading Package Lists".. so yeah thats where the problem is occouring: the reading of package lists stops at 89%.

Comment: If  you only have a command line run- sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list -find those two lines and add a # at the beginning of them to comment them out eg # deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed -this won't remove them just disable them while we fix your update, to activate them again just remove the #. After you # out those lines- sudo apt-get update.

Comment: Mark! thanks a lot , it seems to work when I # deb de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed in the source list. But when I remove the # (after the sudo apt-get update) and i try updating again, it gives me the old error of stopping at 89%. I am thankful that I can now add/remove softwares but I am not sure if the problem that I have is symtomatic of any other deeper issues? Thanks again!

Comment: First remove it - sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed" - add this one I got from the officall site https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed - sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed" -maybe you just had a bad source,